# Isolate a variable within an exponential

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to find the analytical solution to this equation:

Everything is constant except the variable $r$ which I have to isolate

$$\large A\left(1-e^{-B(r-r_e)}\right)=e^{-B'r}$$

Thank you very much for your attention.

Cheers!

Comment: I made the math more readable in your question. Please check that I got it right.

Comment: Are $B$ and $B'$ the same?

Comment: Yes, it is. Thank you!

Comment: Nop, B and B' are not the same.

Comment: Can I ask the context? Maybe this may help in determing what the best way of solving it is. You cannot find a solution in closed form. Are you interested in an approximate solution? The only special case is if $B=0$. Then you can get easily $r$ :-)

Comment: The context is that I need to find out the binding energy between two carbon atoms through the modified morse potential (that's when the derivative = 0) so:

U(r)=De[(1-exp(-B(r-re)))^2-1]+E·exp(-B'·r) ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's much you can do in general.

Substituting $t=e^{-Br}$ gives you

$$\begin{align}
&\Large A-Ae^{Br_e}t=t^{B'/B} \implies \\\\
&\Large t^{B'/B}+Ae^{Br_e}t-A=0 \\
\end{align}$$

This form might give you some more insight in the behavior when plugging in different values for your constants. Solve numerically for a positive $t$, and calculate $r=-{\log t}/{B}$.